# In this code how did we get the second largest element in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

In the below code we are getting largest number by using this  arr[Array.IndexOf(arr, maxNum)] = 0;
but we did nothing to get second largest number we just changed maxNum to secondMaxnum and passed the parameter of secondMaxNum in console.WriteLine and get the second largest number can anyone explain how is this happening..

```
var arr = new int[] { 2, 9, 1, 4, 6 };

var maxNum = arr[0];
foreach (var item in arr)
{
    if (item > maxNum)
        maxNum = item;
}
arr[Array.IndexOf(arr, maxNum)] = 0;

var secondMaxNum = arr[0];
foreach (var item in arr)
{
    if (item > secondMaxNum)
        secondMaxNum = item;
}
Console.WriteLine(secondMaxNum);
```

Comment: because `arr[Array.IndexOf(arr, maxNum)] = 0;` is *not* "getting" the largest number, it is _replacing_ the largest number with 0.  So now, assuming your numbers are positive, when your 2nd loop runs, it finds the "new" max number, which is really the 2nd max number since the first one was set to 0.

Comment: It's just replacing the max with 0 so the second largest number is the new max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Array.IndexOf(arr, maxNum)

is getting the index of your highest number of 9 which is index 1;

> arr[1] = 0;

You are setting the element with index 1 to the value 0;

```
var firstRun = new int[] { 2, 9, 1, 4, 6 };
var secondRun = new int[] { 2, 0, 1, 4, 6 };
```

Answer (score 1):

The two loops are basically doing the same thing, finding the largest number in the array. The important thing is what's happening *between* the two loops:

```
arr[Array.IndexOf(arr, maxNum)] = 0;
```

This is actually setting the largest value to zero, thereby making it less than all the other values. So that the *previously* second highest is now the highest.

Of course, this will only work for very specific data. If all the numbers in the array were negative for example, it would fail spectacularly.

---

It's also not the most *efficient* solution since it has three `O(n)` loops, the two explicit `for` loops and the implicit one in `IndexOf`. You would be better off storing the *index* during the first loop so you don't have to use `IndexOf` at all, something like:

```
var maxIdx = 0;
foreach (var i = 1; i < arr.Length; ++i)
    if (arr[i] > arr[maxIdx])
        maxIdx = i;
arr[maxIdx] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing the same thing in both loops.

AFTER the first loop you set the value of the highest number to 0.

so in the second look you get the highest number (which was the 2nd highest number before you set that the highest to 0)